# Opengeo Geoexplorer WMS source singleTile property?

Tags: wms, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I was wondering whether there is a way to control what layers should be fetched as a single tile in a GeoExplorer composer application?

OpenLayers.Layer.WMS objects have a singleTile property but it does not appear defined for gxp.plugins.WMSSource for instance, so adding the property to a source or a layer in composer.html does not appear to do much.

If the line "var singleTile = false" in WMSSource.js is changed to true then every layer added via Add Layer are single tile, even if the source they belong to (defined in composer.html) is of ptype gxp_wmscsource and the WMS request is "tiled=true", perhaps because WMSCSource extends WMSSource.

If I understand correctly, T.Schaub indicated sources should have a singleTile property sometime in the future here: https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/opengeo_suite1_9_2_community_edition_issues_geoexplorer_white_background

That would allow some control: all layers needing to be served a single tile could be put under one source. Right now things do not appear to work that way, however, so if there is wisdom for some sort of clarification out there I would be glad :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `tiled` option for WMSSource layer definitions, e.g.

```
layers: [{
    source: 'local',
    name: 'usa:states',
    tiled: false
}]
```

This will give you the usa:states layer in single tile mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot! That works as stated. It's defined for a layer that is defined in the composer however; is there a way to make some layers that are part of sources defined in the composer then added via "Add layer" single tile? Setting 'tiled: false' for a source in the composer.html isn't recognized.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this. I would recommend you accept the answer up above to give ahovecar the points and credit and raise this as a new question.